# Error: Invalid character in name at (1), Fortran compiler

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, character

I am trying to compile the following program in Fortran, but the compiler generates the following error message. How can I solve that?

The program:

```
    program exciton
    use mpmodule
    use precision
    implicit none
    type(mp_real)::alfa,beta,gama
    integer,parameter::nmax=3
    integer::li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,i
    type(mp_real)::R1,R2,funcin,funpot& 
    ,He1,Hh1,He2,Hh2,He3,Hh3,He4,Hh4,Hcou,Hpot,He,Hh
    character(80)::strr0,fileoutpote
    real(8)::a0
    call mpinit

    alfa=mpreal(1)
    beta=mpreal(1)
    gama=mpreal(1)
    open(unit=13,file='Elementos/Cine.dat',action="write")
    open(unit=14,file='Elementos/Cinh.dat',action="write")
    open(unit=15,file='Elementos/Cou.dat',action="write")
    do li=0,nmax
        do mi=0,nmax
            do ni=0,nmax
              do lj=0,nmax
                do mj=0,nmax
                    do nj=0,nmax
                        if ( (li+mi+ni .gt. nmax) .or. (lj+mj+nj .gt. nmax)) then
                     continue
                    else
                        He1=(alfa**2+beta**2+gama**2)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(alfa**2+beta**2+gama**2)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(alfa*mpreal(lj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +(alfa*mpreal(lj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,2,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(alfa*mpreal(li))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +(alfa*mpreal(li))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,2,1,nmax)&
                            +(mpreal(li)*mpreal(lj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(li)*mpreal(lj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-2,2,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(beta*mpreal(mj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,-1,1,nmax)&
                            +(beta*mpreal(mj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(beta*mpreal(mi))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,-1,1,nmax)&
                            +(beta*mpreal(mi))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +(mpreal(mi)*mpreal(mj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,-2,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(mi)*mpreal(mj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(gama*mpreal(nj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,0,nmax)&
                            +(gama*mpreal(nj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,0,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(gama*mpreal(ni))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,0,nmax)&
                            +(gama*mpreal(ni))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,0,nmax)&
                            +(mpreal(ni)*mpreal(nj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,-1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(ni)*mpreal(nj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,-1,nmax)

                        Hh1=(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(sh)))*He1    
                        He1=(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(se)))*He1

                        He2=(mpreal(2)*alfa*beta)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(2)*alfa*beta)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*alfa*(mpreal(mi)+mpreal(mj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,-1,1,nmax)&
                            +alfa*(mpreal(mi)+mpreal(mj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*beta*(mpreal(li)+mpreal(lj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +beta*(mpreal(li)+mpreal(lj))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,2,1,nmax)&
                            +(mpreal(li)*mpreal(mj)+mpreal(lj)*mpreal(mi))*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,-1,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(li)*mpreal(mj)+mpreal(lj)*mpreal(mi))&
                            *funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,1,1,nmax)

                        Hh2=(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(sh)))*He2
                        He2=mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(se)))*He2
                        
                        He3=(mpreal(2)*alfa*gama)*(funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,0,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,0,nmax))&
                            +(alfa*(mpreal(ni)+mpreal(nj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,-1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,-1,nmax))&
                            +(gama*(mpreal(li)+mpreal(lj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,0,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,1,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,0,nmax))&
                            +(mpreal(li)*mpreal(nj)+mpreal(lj)*mpreal(ni))*&
                            (funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,-1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,1,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,-1,nmax))
                            
                        He3=(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(se)))*He3

                        Hh3=(mpreal(2)*alfa*gama)*(funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,0,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,0,nmax))&
                            +(alfa*(mpreal(ni)+mpreal(nj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,-1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,-1,nmax))&
                            +(gama*(mpreal(li)+mpreal(lj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,0,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,1,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,0,nmax))&
                            +(mpreal(li)*mpreal(nj)+mpreal(lj)*mpreal(ni))&
                            *(funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,-1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,-1,1,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,-1,nmax))&
                            
                        Hh3=(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(sh)))*Hh3

                        He4=(mpreal(2)*beta*gama)*&
                            (funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,0,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,0,nmax))&
                            +(beta*(mpreal(ni)+mpreal(nj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,-1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,-1,nmax))&
                            +(gama*(mpreal(mi)+mpreal(mj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,-1,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,0,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,0,nmax))&
                            +(mpreal(mi)*mpreal(nj)+mpreal(mj)*mpreal(ni))*&
                            (funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,-1,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,-1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,-1,nmax))&
                            
                        He4=mpreal(-1)*(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(se)))*He4

                        Hh4=(mpreal(2)*beta*gama)*&
                            (funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,0,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,0,nmax))&
                            +(beta*(mpreal(ni)+mpreal(nj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,1,-1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,1,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,2,-1,nmax))&
                            +(gama*(mpreal(mi)+mpreal(mj)))*&
                            (mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,-1,2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,0,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,2,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,0,nmax))&
                            +(mpreal(mi)*mpreal(nj)+mpreal(mj)*mpreal(ni))*&
                            (funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,-1,1,nmax)&
                            +funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,-1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,0,1,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,1,-1,nmax))&
                            
                        Hh4=(mpreal(1)/(mpreal(2)*mpreal(sh)))*Hh4
                        
                        He=mpreal(2)*(mpreal(pi)**2)*(He1+He2+He3+He4)
                        
                        Hh=mpreal(2)*(mpreal(pi)**2)*(Hh1+Hh2+Hh3+Hh4)
                        
                        Hcou=mpreal(2)*(mpreal(pi)**2)*(funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,0,nmax)&
                        +mpreal(-1)*funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,0,nmax))
                        
                        write(13,*)dble(He),li,mi,ni,lj,mj,nj
                        write(14,*)dble(Hh),li,mi,ni,lj,mj,nj
                        write(15,*)dble(Hcou),li,mi,ni,lj,mj,nj
                    end if
                end do
            end do
          end do
        end do
     end do
    end do

   close(unit=13)
   close(unit=14)
   close(unit=15)

do i=1,20
R1=mpreal(i)*mpreal(0.1)
R2=mpreal(i)*mpreal(0.1)
a0=dble(R1)
write(strr0,'(F4.2)')a0
read(strr0,*)a0
fileoutpote='Elementos/Pot '//trim(strr0)//'.dat'
open(unit=16,file=fileoutpote,action="write")
    do li=0,nmax
        do mi=0,nmax
            do ni=0,nmax
                do lj=0,nmax
                    do mj=0,nmax
                        do nj=0,nmax
                            if ((li+mi+ni.gt.nmax) .or. (lj+mj+nj.gt.nmax)) then
                            continue
                            else
                            Hpot=mpreal(2)*(mpreal(pi)**2)*&
                            (funpot(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,0,2,1,R1,R2,nmax)&
                            +mpreal(-1)*funpot(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,2,0,1,R1,R2,nmax))
                            write(16,*)dble(Hpot),li,mi,ni,lj,mj,nj
                            end if
                        end do
                    end do
                end do
            end do
        end do
    end do
  close(unit=16)
  end do

  end program exciton
```

**funcin** and **funpot** are both functions of my program. I use the MPFUN library, therefore **mpinit, mpreal, mpread** are routines from that library

The command that I use to compile the code:

```
gfortran -o exciton.exe precisiones.f90 funcioncinetica.f90 funcionpotencial.f90 exciton.f90 mpfun.o mpmod.o
```

The error message:

```
   87 |                         Hh3=(mpreal(2)*alfa*gama)*(funcin(alfa,beta,gama,li,lj,mi,mj,ni,nj,1,0,2,nmax)&
      |                                     1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
exciton.f90:109:37:

  109 |                         He4=(mpreal(2)*beta*gama)*&
      |                                     1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
exciton.f90:132:37:

  132 |                         Hh4=(mpreal(2)*beta*gama)*&
      |                                     1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

In the command that I enter in the compiler **precisiones.f90** is a module, **funcioncinetica.f90** funcionpotencial.f90 are functions of my program and **exciton.f90** is my main program. **mpfun.o** and **mpmod.o** are modules of MPFUN, a library that I am using

I would be very grateful if you could solve it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Did you check your parentheses? We may need a full piece of code that we can try to compile ourselves. We certainly need the declarations of all your arrays or functions. See [mcve]. Please add more code. It can be simplified code, but we should be able to get your error message.

Comment: The exact command you used to compile the code could be useful as well

Comment: gfortran -o exciton.exe precisiones.f90 funcioncinetica.f90 funcionpotencial.f90 exciton.f90 mpfun.o mpmod.o.

There is everything that I introduce to the compiler.
precisiones.f90 is a module, funcioncinetica.f90 funcionpotencial.f90 are functions of my program and exciton.f90 is my main program. mpfun.o and mpmod.o are modules of MPFUN, a library that I am using

Comment: I edited the post and added more information

Comment: Which MPFUN do you use? There are many versions. Please show the function declaration. Don't they require character arguments?

Comment: There is no declaration for `He1` in your code.

Comment: There I corrected it, He1 had been erased in the copy and paste. the mpreal function can receive an integer and returns a real with the precision specified in MPFUN. I built a simple program to test it and it works like that. I suspect that the problem is in the use of "&" to truncate the lines

Comment: You forgot an `&` at the end of your expression. It cannot be there. Only if the line continues on the next line.

Comment: Yes !, that was it! now my program works. Thank you very much, now I am learning to like you and I close the post :D